# Create customize json map from shapefiles

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, maps, r-highcharter

I use the highcharter package to make maps in R Shiny applications.
I would like to use a map with on a more detailed level than the ones provided here :
https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/
For example I use the .json file of "France Admin2" which displays the DOM below France mainland.
https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/fr/fr-all-all.svg

What I would like to do is to be able to create the same .json file from a shapefiles file.
To be precise, I have a .shp for mainland France and another one for the DOM.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to create a custom map, right? Here you can read about it: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/create-custom-maps-for-highmaps and https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps

Comment: Many thanks @raf18seb !